# SSRS - How to remove whitespace in report body?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that contains a table in the body and a footer. The problem is that the rows stop displaying half way down the report, and move on to the next page, leaving a huge amount of whitespace on the first page.

Is there any way to resolve this?

[image: Whitespace]

Comment: have you checked your page size and report size settings. Make sure your report size is thee page size minus the margins.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple groups or tablix make sure there aren't any page breaks on them.

Comment: I bet that footer is static height and is being applied to all pages. Another option to using a footer is to put a parent group around everything and put your footer in the parent groups footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report page size was too big. Adjusting it solved my problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your report page size. Incresing the height should solve it.